# How to change the Text value of a Textblock from the property of a class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Please excuse for my low level in WPF. I encounter an issue with my project. I have a formular in a usercontrol, which is displayed to the user when he click on a tab. I also stock the value of the name's tab into an property of my abstract class. I want the formular to be filled with the associated properties of the name's tab.

To do this, I know that I need to use the binding method with the text's property of my textblock. I tried many way to implement that, but they all failed.

Let show some code, there is my xaml :

```
<TextBlock Name="nomEcole" Text="{Binding NomEcole, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" Margin="10,10,0,0" />
```

There is the user control :

```
public partial class EcoleControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void FirePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private string _nomEcole;
    public string NomEcole
    {
        get { return MainWindow._RE.EcoleVisualisee.Nom; }
        set
        {
            if (MainWindow._RE.EcoleVisualisee.Nom != value)
            {
                MainWindow._RE.EcoleVisualisee.Nom = value;
                this.FirePropertyChanged("NomEcole");
            }
        }
    }

    public EcoleControl()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And there is my abstract class (The value of _nomEcoleVisualisee is updated by a method) :

```
class RelationEcoles
{
    private string _nomEcoleVisualisee;
    public string NomEcoleVisualisee
    {
        get { return _nomEcoleVisualisee; }
        set { this._nomEcoleVisualisee = value; }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help ! I also wanted to know, I don't really know if my project looks like  MVVM.

Comment: not really mvvm, you have inverted : user control must not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but RelationEcoles. Please have a look to existing code because you are going the wrong way

Comment: So where are you setting the NomEcole property that you bind to?

Comment: @mm8 I set it in a method of RelationEcoles class, When I click on a modern tab link, I apply the method to change the value of the property.

Comment: So the RelationEcoles  has a reference to the UserControl? This makes no sense and certainly breaks the MVVM pattern. Please post some reproducible code.

Comment: Can I send you my project by mail or something like that ? the only problème is that take my data from a database that you cannot acces from your device.

Comment: No. You should provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example or delete the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You could also upload a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example some where and post the link to it here.

Comment: I tried to provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, it's impossible due to the access to the database. I have done some test on variables during the visualisation of the binding, and all variables are correct axcept for the datacontext, I think that I don't initialize it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Binding will not work like this because your property is located in the .cs file of your usercontrol.

Usually you would have a `EcoleViewModel` which implements `INPC` and hold the property like this:

```
public class EcoleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void FirePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private string _nomEcole;
    public string NomEcole
    {
        get { return MainWindow._RE.EcoleVisualisee.Nom; }
        set
        {
            if (MainWindow._RE.EcoleVisualisee.Nom != value)
            {
                MainWindow._RE.EcoleVisualisee.Nom = value;
                this.FirePropertyChanged("NomEcole");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can set the `DataContext`in the ctor of your usercontrol like this:

```
 public EcoleControl()
    {
        this.DataContext = new EcoleViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Now the binding should work.

Comment: OP sets the DataContext to the current instance of EcoleControl, which contains NomEcole property. It's basically the same to what you did. And the fact that it's in xaml.cs file doesn't matter for bindings, bindings are looking inside DataContext. Having a separate class for ViewModel is not mandatory and I would doubt that it would solve the problem.

Comment: @3615 OP was also asking if he is violating the `MVVM` pattern or not. But you are right, solution just moves the property to a viewmodel and binds to an instance of that instead. Nevertheless this binding should work, if not you could try to hold a private field of type `string` and use that instead of `Nom` property somewhere on the `MainViewModel`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution but It still didn't work. It seems that the name of the property isn't updated when it change.

Comment: @BallyMathieu It is really hard to figure out what the problem is, since we do not know what your getter and setter are really doing. Can you try use the `_nomEcole` field as a backing field for the `NomEcole` property in the `EcoleViewModel` and check your Output Window for any error messages?

Comment: I think that the binding work because it display the original name that I instance in the constructor. But the displayed name didn't change when the property change. Maybe there is an event missing ?

Comment: @BallyMathieu Can you please explain what you have done? Are you using the `_nomEcole` as a backing field as I suggested? It sounds like you are using a property on another class like `RelationEcoles` which doesn't implement `INPC`. In this case it's clear why the view won't get updated.

Comment: I done exactly as you said, I created a new class which implement INPC and a property NomEcole, this property refer to the property of RelationEcoles property's.

Comment: @BallyMathieu Then you did not do what I told you and it's clear why the view is not updated. See my post above.

Comment: I implement the INPC in RelationEcoles where my property is located. It seems that property is updated, but the datacontext is null. I pute this in my datacontext :

Comment: this.DataContext = MainWindow._RE.EcoleVisualisee;